# Reading progress of Git operation using GitPython stuck

Tags: python, git, python-3.7, gitpython

I'm trying to access the progress of time consuming Git operations using GitPython. I tried the sample solution taken from the official documentation, and also tried passing in a method following the exact signature of the update method below. Everytime I call `fetch()`, `push()`, `pull()` **with** the parameter `progress=<anything>`, the programm is stuck and the `update` method does not get called. If I call those operations without setting the `progress` parameter, it works flawlessly.

- I use `asserts` to assure my repo objects are available and in the expected state
- `ProgressPrinter()` yields not `None`
- I tried calling the functions from the main thread and multithreaded
- I took a look at the [implementation (line 350)](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/52ee33ac9b234c7501d97b4c2bf2e2035c5ec1fa/git/util.py#L350) of `RemoteProgress` and also the [implementation (line 815)](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/blob/52ee33ac9b234c7501d97b4c2bf2e2035c5ec1fa/git/remote.py#L815) of `push()` and do not see a reason, why it would not continue execution
- I found out, that when I assign my `ProgressPrinter` instance and pass the assigned variable, the programm is not stuck anymore. Yet the `update()` method does not get called and no progress is printed

```py
# Not stuck anymore, yet no progress
pp = ProgressPrinter()
fetch_info = origin.fetch(progress=pp)
```

Core of my implementation:

```py
from git import RemoteProgress

class ProgressPrinter(RemoteProgress):
    def update(self,
               op_code,
               cur_count,
               max_count=None,
               message=''):
        print("Is this even called?")
```

And later on:

```py
origin = repo.remotes.origin
assert origin.exists()
fetch_info = origin.fetch(progress=ProgressPrinter())
```

Any recommendations on how to investigate this problem furthermore? I've been debugging this for one day now and feel like I am missing something.

Comment: Have you verified your git version?

Comment: `git --version` is 2.21.0

Comment: Have you tried `sys.stdout.flush()` after `print`? Maybe it's buffering?

Comment: Just tried it, without effect.

Comment: It's been a few years since I tried to do something similar, and discovered that Git itself has a bug where the progress text is not sent in some cases. If that bug has not been fixed, nothing you do in your Python code can work around it.

Comment: Do you remember the circumstances under which Git progress didn't respond properly? I was curious and just cloned the official Git repository to look through progress related commits: Progress seems to be in very active development and I would guess the problem would be fixed by now. Do not rule it out though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. GitPython getting stuck when processing the progress information**

Over the last couple of months localization changes have been made to Git. Downgrading my Git from `2.21.0` to `2.20.4` solved this problem for now. Not an elegant solution, but the developers of GitPython know about the changes.

*Take a peek at the issue and see if it's solved: [(Github Issue #871)](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/871)*

**2. `RemoteProgress`'s `update()` method not being called**

If your Git process finishes quickly, this method won't be called at all. To simulate a longer process I suggest you clone a large repository from Github / Gitlab and prepare it in the following way:

```sh
$ git reset --hard @~100
$ git remote remove origin
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
$ git remote add origin <url>
```

I proposed to change the `update()` method in a way, that it is also called *once* when the operation terminates with `= [up to date]`: [PullRequest](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/pull/872)